# Content-Security-Policy refused to connect to

Tags: security, http-headers, content-security-policy

> Refused to connect to
>   'https://w1xxx.ldxxx.net:7031/direct/v1609/something?preview=FALSE'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval 'self' *.googleapis.com
>   *.google-analytics.com *.gstatic.com *.googletagmanager.com aaa.dev.someplace.com *.test.ldxxx.net *.testauto.ldxxx.net
>   w1xxx.ldxxx.net aaa.xxz.ldxxx.net aaa.test.someplace.com
>   aaa.staging.aaac.net aaa.yyy.ddd.as.nz". Note that 'connect-src' was
>   not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Bearing in mind I have masked the urls as to not give away sensitive information.

My exact content-security-policy http header is in the quoted error text. The error stated that:

```
https://w1xxx.ldxxx.net:7031/direct/v1609/something?preview=FALSE
```

violates my content-security-policy. But why? Shouldn't `https://w1xxx.ldxxx.net:7031/direct/v1609/something?preview=FALSE` be allowed to be connected to, because of `w1xxx.ldxxx.net` in my content-security-policy?

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL of the page where the policy is defined, and where this violation occurs?

If this page is not served on port 7031, you would have to specify `w1xxx.ldxxx.net:7031` as the host entry in your policy.

Per the [CSP specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#grammardef-port-part), if the port isn't specified, it defaults to the port from the URL's scheme (default HTTPS uses 443).

> If expression does not contain a port-part, and url’s port is not the
>   default port for url’s scheme, return "Does Not Match".

Comment: The page is served on port 7031. The solution was `https://w1xxx.ldxxx.net:7031`. Had to specify the port and nothing after the port. As per your answer I wouldn't need to specify the port would I since the host is on port 7031 and so is the web server we are making a call to connect to.